# Rendering sharp shadow on cycle rendering

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, light, shaders

I would generate a clear shadow projected on a floor. I am wondering what is the essential node used to achieve this.

I am using these nodes 
[image]

and I get this image, I remark that the shadow is blurred (a lot of penumbra). I fix the focus at the floor and I try to change the Aperture (F/stop) to fit the depth of field. 
[image]

Comment: Do you mean clear as in not blurry, ie sharp?

Comment: @RayMairlot, I edit my text. I mean it is blurred

Comment: on sun, point and spot lamps, you can reduce the size to get sharp shadows

Comment: @Bithur, It is possible to reduce the penumbra?

Comment: @startingBlender Scale it down alot. The larger a light source the softer the shaodw. If your light source is tiny, you shadows will be sharp

Comment: @GiantCowFilms, you mean I scale the point light? I scale it 0.01 but it does not change the result!

Comment: @startingBlender with secondary light(s). can be set to no "cast shadow" if needed

Comment: don't scale the object but use the light property "size"

Comment: @Bithur, Thanks it works! What did this property change?

Comment: it changed the size of the emission point.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unwanted sharp shadows when using a point lamp](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18012/unwanted-sharp-shadows-when-using-a-point-lamp)

Comment: @Jerryno That question is very similar, and the answer to that question may solve this one, but the question itself is asking a different thing (how to get sharp shadows vs. how to get blurrier shadows with a point lamp).  See [this meta post](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/549/duplicate-answer-vs-duplicate-question), the answers cover the same thing but the questions are different.

Comment: @PGmath then they should be just linked? ok

Answer (score 13, accepted):

reduce the size property of your lamp.

[image]

[image]

Comment: very nicely explained!

Answer (score 6):

Making this size smaller makes the shadow sharper:

[image]