# Black reflections with Cycle's Glossy Material

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

This is a common problem I've found in a few jobs related with ocean. When the camera is close to the surface, looking at the horizon, those black areas appear. Either with a normal texture or not.

[image]
[image]

It looks there's a problem with ocean's self reflection, but I can't avoid this by adjusting the bounces. Any ideas?

[Here is the .blend file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4bi5po7chyggyhg/ocean_problems.rar?dl=0). As you can see, the environment is visible only through camera and glossy, and the problem keeps with a blank environment too. The scene is lit with a sun lamp and plain color environment.

Comment: I assume you are using an environment texture, so the lighting is even?

Comment: Could you [post a .blend](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/) with the images packed into it?

Comment: This is normal behavior, but I am not sure exactly why. The .blend would help a lot

Comment: I've just posted the .blend file. The images are not the same, but it wasn't HDR so the results are the same.

Comment: I checked most of the common causes (bad environment, normals, bad material setup) and none of these seem to be the problem. I am guessing it's either a bug or the limitation of what Cycles can simulate.

Comment: Bad news then... What about avoiding the sea from self-reflecting? I think I tried this once, but I didn't like the result actually. I think that could be an approach.

Comment: Can you try subdividing the mesh? I find black reflections on low-poly objects when their normals are "smooth" shaded. Subdividing solves that problems. It's probably related to the termination problem.

Comment: I'm afraid that subdiv doesn't fix the problem at all. Also, the black reflections occurred even when there's no normal map.

Comment: Try increasing the *glossy* or *transmission* bounces under the *light paths* rollout of the *render* panel.

Comment: It seems real ocean has the same black spots effect. Maybe Cycles works right. though they are not so harsh. [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hykTL.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hykTL.jpg)

Comment: What happens in that image is that on those waves, the water is facing the camera so the Fresnel effect let us to see the sea bottom. They're not black spots, maybe they appear black because the photograph exposition. As I remember this effect happens when the material is only glossy -with no refraction- so it's not the same effect in my opinion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not completely sure what's causing this, I suspect it is just how Cycles works and is not strictly a bug - similar to the [terminator issue](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1998/cycles-shadows-on-smooth-shaded-mesh-strange-behavior).

In order to work around it, we can modify the surface normals slightly in the material:

[image: fixed]

From [the manual](http://blender.org/manual/render/cycles/nodes/input.html#geometry):

> **Incoming**
>
> Vector pointing towards the point the shading point is being viewed from.

Thus adding a *tiny* bit of the Incoming vector will skew the surface normal just enough to hide the artifacts.

*Note that changing the surface normal means our reflections will be incorrect - so we need to change it as little as possible, otherwise the reflections of objects and clouds will be noticeably weird.*

Answer (score 0):

Your ocean shader's glossy and refraction nodes need a bit roughness (more than 0).
[image]

Comment: While increasing roughness hides the problem slightly (but not entirely), it really has nothing to do with the cause.

Comment: did not find anything better

Answer (score -1):

[image: Smooth shaded Reflections- bug]

I think that there is generally a problem about shading of glossy materials with "fake normals".
Even if you smooth an object, this problem is there, but it isn't, if you don't adjust the normals.

Comment: The reason your sphere has black edges is because it has not been subdivided.

Comment: @10Replies That is not a reason to have the black edges, but yes the sphere is not subdivided as far as it could be, and subdividing it further may appear to fix the problem...you reach a point when you don't want to keep subdividing because the blend gets too complex for your computer.

Comment: @pycoder, the black edge effect is much more subtle from a distance, so if you have something with many objects, you really don't need subsurf except up close. Also, the asker said "Subdiv doesn't fix the problem at all."