# Black spots on the ocean

Tags: shaders, geometry, ocean-simulation

I have a plane with ocean modifier but it has some black patches when you gaze at it from a certain angle. What can it be? Maybe this is fine effect for an ocean? increasing ocean resolution doesn't seem to solve the problem. [image: Spots] [image: Ocean settings] [image: Node setup]

Comment: you have one quite dark glossy shader there .. could this be the problem? To be honest I'm still not completely through the nodes ;)
Now I think it also might have to do something with your displacement and seeing some faces "from behind" as they get displaced to a concav shape

Comment: Dark glossy doesn't seem to be a problem.

Comment: There was a similar question asked a while ago. Maybe your issue is sililar:https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/24852/1853

Comment: The problem could be the normal computation, I have noticed some triangle do not create a continuous mesh at times.