# What is vertex and edge shading?

Tags: modeling, mesh, light

I know how shading works with faces:

[image: Smooth cylinder]
[image: Flat cylinder]

That's set by choosing *Smooth*/*Flat* under *Faces* in the *Shading* menu:

[image: Shading - Faces: (Smooth/Flat) - Edges: (Smooth/Sharp) - Vertices: (Smooth/Sharp)]

But what do the other two options—*Edges* and *Vertices*—do?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This feature makes it possible to sharpen or soften **individual components** of a mesh instead of soften or sharpen the entire mesh. Especially for *Low Poly Modeling* it can be useful to have more control about the object's appearance and thus to define a more complex shape with less geometry.

[image]

Result of sharpen the selected **edges only**:

[image]

**Note:** In Order to make it work, enable *Auto Smooth* Option in the *Properties Panel > Data*.

When sharpening **vertices**, the *connected edges* are also affected:

[image]

**Render result** of sharpen edges only:

[image]

Comment: This is very useful if you *want* to create a [Terminator effect](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1998/2217)... :)