# Weird shadow in rendered image

Tags: rendering

Here's the rendered image. The problem is with the shadows on the green object's right side. It's like a weird wave shaped shadow. And I get this result in all my renders where I use subsurf and smooth shading. I don't know if it has anything to do with them. Help if you can, please. 
Many thanks[image]

I've tried a few changes based on the two links, but it's still the same. So gandalf3, it's not the same question, the problem is different, as it seems.

Comment: Related answer: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/26577/2217

Comment: @atlas, you can upload the .blend to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/  . When using images to convey an issue it's  worth hiding extra geometry and place the camera so that the unwanted feature becomes more prominent.