# What are the light blue lines on my imported objects

Tags: import, edges

So recently, I have been noticing neon light blue lines on objects I import, in place of the the normal orange selection lines. Maybe I was supposed to be getting this variant of line before hand or maybe I just somehow haven't noticed it till now. But assumptions aside, I'm wondering what this line is for and how can I get rid of the light blue lines? Also Along with this my objects that are imported seem to  have their faces turn from gray to white.

[image]

Comment: regarding the faces, I believe it's a separate question. Maybe [upload a selection of the mesh](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) which exhibits this behavior or show more screenshots.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26576/what-is-vertex-and-edge-shading

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This means in Shading/UVs those edges have been marked as *Sharp*:

> The Sharp mark is used by the split normals and the Edge Split modifier, which are part of the smoothing or customized shading techniques. As seams, it is a property of edges, and these operators set or unset it for selected ones.

See the manual: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/edge/edge_data.html#mark-sharp-clear-sharp

---

As for **clearing *sharp* edges**, open up the *Edge* menu (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>) and select *Clear Sharp*:

[image]

In 2.7 versions, this can be done here from the *Tool Panel* <kbd>T</kbd> *> Shading*:

[image]

But this UI doesn't appear to be supremely intuitive (October 2015). it seems you have to click Sharp first before that panel becomes visible.

---

Here's a script that lets you

- Mark selected edges as sharp
- Or remove sharp status of a set of selected edges

Code for *Object Mode*:

```
import bpy

obj = bpy.context.object
for e in obj.data.edges:
    if e.select:
        # invert current state
        e.use_edge_sharp = (not e.use_edge_sharp)
```

Answer (score 5):

Select all edges and press <kbd>Crtl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> Clear Sharp and Mark Sharp are under Mark/Clear Seam.

Answer (score 3):

For Blender 2.8+ you can toggle the visibility of marked edges under the drop-down *Overlays* at the top of the viewport.

Toggle the *Sharp* option.