# modifying vertices of an imported obj object

Tags: mesh, edges, bevel, obj

[![What I'm trying to do here is to create distinction lines just like in cars. I modeled it in Fusion360 and imported it to Blender as obj. First I selected those edges that are highlighted as light blue and moved them lower to create a gap between the other surface. Then, I extruded the edges towards the inside(so it's not visible from this angle). I did that to create a bevel, but it won't do anything. I'm suspecting that the edges(highlighted light blue) somehow have a problem because normally edges are white when selected. What could be a possible issue that I can solve? THANKS! ][1]][1]

What I'm trying to do here is to create distinction lines just like in cars. I modeled it in Fusion360 and imported it to Blender as obj. First I selected those edges that are highlighted as light blue and moved them lower to create a gap between the other surface. Then, I extruded the edges towards the inside(so it's not visible from this angle). I did that to create a bevel, but it won't do anything. I'm suspecting that the edges(highlighted light blue) somehow have a problem because normally edges are white when selected. What could be a possible issue that I can solve? THANKS!
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdlA1.jpg

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40292/what-are-the-light-blue-lines-on-my-imported-objects?rq=1 for the blue lines.