# My surfaces are cut by blues lines, how to merge these sub surfaces together?

Tags: mesh

I have imported a file that someone gave me and it appears that all the surfaces are cut in smaller surfaces that touch each other.

These "cuts" are visible in blue in the image below:

[image: surface cut in pieces]

**Edit** clear the sharp edges as suggested by Harry does get rid of the blue line in the editor but still does not merge the surfaces.

If I (1) select an vertex at on of those interface:

[image]

And (2) move it with `G`, here is what I see: **A hole**

[image]

How can I fix this? I would like to glue the two surfaces together.

Comment: There is nothing to fuse. Those blue lines are just marked as *Sharp* edges. Just select everything with `A` and then `Ctrl+E` *>Clear Sharp* to remove clear sharp edges. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40292/what-are-the-light-blue-lines-on-my-imported-objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Select one of the edges that are marked as sharp (blue)
2. Expand the selection to cover all of them by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> -> "Sharpness"
3. Merge close vertices through <kbd>m</kbd> -> "by distance"
4. adjust the distance so that most vertices are combined
5. Manually merge remaining vertex pairs by selecting them and pressing <kbd>m</kbd> -> (option)

The first two steps make sure we only merge the points that are on the seam.
If you want smooth shading across the seam, you can still clear the sharp mark afterwards like @Wiseman said.

Comment: I tried this solution. To help the merge by distance I also Subdivided the edges to create closer vertices in order to be able to then chose a smaller merge distance. This method works well but unfortunately the shape I have has too many different scales that it is had to come up with a good merge distance that does not introduce artefacts.

Comment: If the shapes themselves are uniform enough you can try hiding the other regions before doing that. However bad topology will always require extra effort to fix or work around.

Answer (score 0):

They are "Marked as Sharp", not separated. If you wanna remove them, select the mesh and right click "clear sharp" but that sometimes makes the mesh awkward looking.