# Object won't smooth shade?

Tags: rendering

I created a scene with some popcorn but am having a weird error where the objects won't smooth shade anymore. Below is a blend file with an example of one of the popcorn kernels:

Blend file: [image]

Comment: Toggle into *Edit Mode*, *Select all*, go to *Shading UV's > Edges* and click *Smooth*. Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26576/what-is-vertex-and-edge-shading/26577#26577

Comment: I think closing this as a duplicate is a case of Duplicate Answer vs Duplicate question (http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/549/duplicate-answer-vs-duplicate-question), so this should be reopened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In *Edit Mode* <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> and click 'Clear Sharp'

Comment: Thanks for the help! The weird thing is it was modeled in blender originally and I never marked the any edges as sharp. I set them to smooth before exporting as obj. It defaulted to that when it was imported as an obj and the uv seams were lost. Is this how Blender usually works with objs?

Comment: No that's not how Blender usually works with Obj's. Maybe you went to click the Smooth button and hit Sharp by mistake. Luckily it's an easy fix :)

Comment: I went back to the original and deleted the location, rotation, and scale data with Ctrl + A. The smooth shading worked great afterwards. It looks like sometimes if you dramatically change the model and don't delete the location, rotation, scale data it might mess things up when exporting to obj. I didn't delete that data on the original when it started having the smooth problem. Patdog's answer also works if the obj is having the smoothing problem.