# Low poly mesh interrupting normal map in render

Tags: rendering, uv, blender-internal-render-engine, normals, normal-map

I have been looking for a solution to my problem for 3 hours and unfortunately I can't find it anywhere, so I have to ask.

**When I add a normal map with hi poly mesh, the edges of the object are obscured by the low poly mesh. It's looks like this:**

[image]

Hi-poly mesh looks like this:

[image]

I also found this problem in a new open file:

[image]

hi poly mesh:

[image]

**Any suggestions why the object does not display as it should?**

-There are no duplicated objects below low poly mesh

-I tryed recalculate normals

-I have setup non color data

-I using Blender 2.79B

-Before beake i choose hi-poly mesh first

-It is already setup the same location for both objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only so much a normal map can do, see for example [this tutorial](http://blenderdiplom.com/en/tutorials/all-tutorials/589-tutorial-normal-baking-with-cycles.html) for an in depth explanation of how it works and what the limitations are. TLDW; changes to the silhouette cannot be represented in a normal map. For situations like your second example a normal map cannot give any close approximation of the original appearance. You could try [vector displacement](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/nodes/types/vector/vector_displacement.html) instead if you want.

That said, your first example should be doable with a normal map.

- Make sure your low poly object is smooth shaded before baking.
- Try adding a little geometry to sort of follow the contour of the high poly mesh (even simply beveling will help reduce [terminator artifacts](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1998/599))